# C#6 - char.MinValue().ToString() not outputting to rich text box

Tags: c#

I was attempting to output all the min and max values of the simple data types using C# 6's new formatting into a rich text box. But where it calls char.MinValue it stops outputting the string.

[image: Output]

The following code is shortened to give an example and show just the problem I'm having. MaxChar() causes no problems but anywhere I put MinChar() the string quits outputting. I am seeing no errors when trying to debug, and the method is concatenating everything when I look at the local variables using breakpoints. So I was thinking it might have something to do with the rich text box, but I cannot find anything that leads me to understand why this is happening.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Text = setTextBox();
    }

    private string setTextBox()
    {
        String output = "";

        // decimal
        output += "decimal\t" +
                $"\tMin: " + MinDecimal() + "\n" +
                $"\t\tMax: " + MaxDecimal() + "\n";
        // char
        output += "char\t" +
                $"\tMin: " + MinChar() + " to " +
                $"Max: " + MaxChar() + "\n";

        return output;
    }

    public string MinChar()
    {
        return $"{char.MinValue.ToString()}";
    }

    public string MaxChar()
    {
        return $"{char.MaxValue.ToString()}";
    }
```

I currently have it casting my char.MinValue to an int ((int)char.MinValue) before calling ToString(), and that works just fine, but of course it's outputting the int value of the char. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`char.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`char.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return a `char` datatype. This means that `char.MinValue` is actually `\0`, which is the string terminator character. `RichTextBox` understands it as such and doesn't output the remainder of the string.

You can see that if you check the value of `output` in the debugger:

```
"decimal\t\tMin: -79228162514264337593543950335\n\t\tMax: 79228162514264337593543950335\nchar\t\tMin: \0 to Max: \uffff\n"
```

Comment: It is important to note that this is the *native* string terminator character. .NET has no problems with strings containing zero chars.

Comment: @usr it have. I met same problem before. .NET string can contain \0 in middle of string but be truncate when display

Comment: Thanks guys. I had thought it was something like that and I tried to escape it before to test that theory since I can't explicitly state it. But with this info I found a handy-dandy method that outputs literals.